# The derivative $\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}f(x) \text{ }dx \bigg)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

We know that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \text{ }dt \bigg)=f(x).$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here $t$ is the variable of integration. Is the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}f(x) \text{ }dx \bigg)$$

the same case with the former, with the only exception that the choice of the symbol for the variable of integration is poor in the latter? My logic says that it is so, it would not change anything if the variable of integration is labeled $x$ or $t$ (apart from creating confusion, that is).

**EDIT**

It did turn out to be a typo, it was supposed to be $\int_{a}^{x}f(t) \text{ }dt$

Comment: Most would say the second one doesn't have meaning, so you can't even talk about stuff like its derivative.

Comment: The second one makes about as much sense as $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{i}f(i)$$ does.

Answer (score 4):

Your second expression is ambiguous in the sense that it could mean either

$$\frac{d}{d\color{blue}{x}}\left(\int_{a}^{\color{blue}{x}}f(\color{red}{x})\,d\color{red}{x} \right)\text{ or }\frac{d}{d\color{blue}{x}}\left(\int_{a}^{\color{blue}{x}}f(\color{blue}{x})\,d\color{red}{x} \right).$$

If we interpret it to mean the former, then yes, it has the exact same meaning as if $\color{red}x$ were $t$ instead. The choice of symbol for a variable makes no difference. If we interpret it to mean the latter, then your first and second expressions are not generally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The integral
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\int_{a}^{x}f(x) \text{ }dx \bigg)
$$
is ambiguous. You can't reuse the integration variable outside the integrand.

Comment: Actually, it isn't really ambiguous. It's sloppy writing, but really, the integrated value doesn't really "come into contact" with anything outside the integral, so you can call it anything, even $x$.

Comment: @5xum: I agree. The scope of the variables bound by $\mathrm{d}x$, i.e. the $x$ in $f(x)$, is within the integral. The bounds of the integration are outside that scope. Thus, $\int_a^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.